# position of recaptcha on bootstrap

Tags: html, css, recaptcha

I'm trying to align recaptcha box with input fields using bootstrap. I used this code on ckeditor. The position of recaptcha changed when the time out for captcha was display. How to keep the position of recaptcha box same even after display error?

```css
.g-recaptcha {
    margin-left: -1px!important;
    margin-top: -50px
}
width: 300px; !important;
.captcha{
 margin-left:7px;
 margin-top:-47px!important;
}
.recaptcha-wrap {
 position:relative;
 height:76px;
 padding:1px 0 0 1px;
 background:#222;
>div{
 position:absolute;
 bottom: 2px;
 right:2px;
 font-size:10px;
 color:#ccc;
 }
}
width: 300px; !important;
.captcha{
 margin-left:7px;
 margin-top:-47px!important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<form class="well form-horizontal" action=" " method="post" 
    id="contact">
  
  <div class="form-group">
<div class="col-md-8 inputGroupContainer">
<div class="input-group required"><span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope" ></i> </span> <input class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" type="text" value="" /></div>
</div>
</div>
  
<div class="form-group">
<div class="col-md-8 inputGroupContainer">
<div class="input-group required"><span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" ></i> </span> <input class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name" type="text" value="" /></div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
<div class="col-md-8 inputGroupContainer">
<div class="input-group">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
<div class="col-md-8 inputGroupContainer">
<div class="input-group captcha"><input data-error="Check `I am human` !" id="recaptchaValidator" name="recaptcha" pattern="1" required="" style="visibility: hidden" type="text" value="" />
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-callback="test" data-sitekey="6Lc7vh8UAAAAAEkcVjo-Cz5rOKSmE22V7x8-0MXP" name="">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
        
   
 </form>
```

Comment: It seems aligned in your snippet (Chrome 59 on Mac)

Comment: position changed after session expired